# MongoDB query to retrieve distinct documents by date

Tags: mongodb, date, datetime

I have documents in the database with a dateTime value like so:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a66fa22d29dbd0001521023"),
    "exportSuccessful" : true,
    "month" : 0,
    "week" : 4,
    "weekDay" : "Mon",
    "dateTime" : ISODate("2018-01-22T09:02:26.525Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I'd like to:

1. query the database for a given date and have it return the document that contains the dateTime if the date matches (I don't care about the time). This is mainly to test before inserting a document that there isn't already one for this date.  In the above example, if my given date is `2018-01-22` I'd like the document to be returned.
2. retrieve all documents with a distinct date from the database (again, I don't care about the time portion). If there are two documents with the same date (but different times), just return the first one.

From what I understand Mongo's ISODate type does not allow me to store only a date, it will always have to be a dateTime value. And on my side, I don't have control over what goes in the database.

Comment: is the given date a string value or a date value with time set to zero ?

Comment: @Veeram I can do both, I am using moment.js for date manipulation on the client end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try range query with start date time from start of the day to end date time to end of the day. So basically create dates a day apart.

Something like

```
var start = moment().utc().startOf('day');
var end = moment().utc().endOf('day');

db.collection.find({
    dateTime: {
        $gte: start,
        $lte: end
    }
})
```

Get all distinct dates documents:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
 {"$group":{
  "_id":{
    "$dateToString":{"format":"%Y-%m-%d","date":"$dateTime"}
  },
  "first":{
    "$first":"$$ROOT"
  }
}}])
```

Comment: Thanks @Veeram, I'll give this a try. The `$$ROOT` in the second snippet looks like magic, could you explain please?

Comment: Yw. $$ROOT to output the whole document. More [`here`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/)